# How can one measure spatial clustering of continuous (non-count) data?

Tags: variance, clustering, poisson-distribution, beta-distribution, ecology

I am currently teaching an ecology class how to use the variance to mean ratio (VMR) as a method for looking at the spatial clustering of individual organisms across a landscape. This method takes the number of individuals in each "plot" and compares it to a Poisson distribution. If the distribution of the data fits the assumption of the Poisson curve ($\lambda = \mu = \sigma^2$) then they are randomly dispersed, but if the data are overdispersed ($\mu < \sigma^2$) or underdispersed ($\mu > \sigma^2$) then the organisms are significantly clustered or spread out, respectively.

The issue I'm having stems from a lab activity they do. They look at 8 "plots" of a plant species and get the percent cover (0 - 100) of the plant in each plot, then use those 8 values for a VMR analysis. This is, of course, creates multiple massive artefacts that excessively bias it towards overdispersion, such as the fact that percent cover is continuous, there is an arbitrary cap on the data at a value of 100, and percent cover is not generated by a Poisson process.

Here is my question: How could one analyze spatial clustering, given the data I've described above? My thought is that it will involve the beta distribution, but the ways that one would compare $\mu, \sigma^2, \alpha$ and $\beta$ in that situation escapes me. I'm also thinking there might be a method involving the negative binomial and a modified $\kappa$ term, but that doesn't fix the count vs. continuous issue

All help is greatly appreciated!